# CSS position:absolute destroys layout after element

Tags: css

I got a DIV in my HTML-Markup, which is positioned relative. The DIVs inside this container are absolute.

this destroys the complete layout, because the following HTML-Elements are now positioned wrong, the (above) DIV which is relative, overflows them...
but why? How can I fix it?

Comment: So... I'm sorry that you're encountering layout issues. For the community to help, can you please provide the specific code that is giving you troubles. A working example is best, if it's not overloaded with non relevant content

Answer (score 0):

Once you position a container with `:relative`, everything inside it will be positioned in relation to that. The `position:absolute` pulls the child elements out of the flow of the page an positions them at the top of the container with `position:relative`.

Thus, once you have elements with `position:relative`, you will want to also add rules to move and position the child elements. Consider using `left:` and `top:` or `right:` and `bottom` to position your `:absolute` child elements.

Alternatively, you might try to position the child elements with `:relative` as well, if you don't want them pulled out of the flow of the page.

Do you have code to look at, or a jsfiddle? Otherwise it's difficult to know what's going on and to suggest a fix.

Answer (score 0):

If your relatively-positioned element *only* contains  absolutely-positioned elements, you need to give it a `height` setting, otherwise it will have zero height (the absolutely-positioned elements won't be counted for auto height), and therefore probably cause some overlapping with subsequent elements.